# Separate RigidBod2D rotation from Sprite

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Using Unity 2D I would like to allow it to use a Rigidbody2D, but i want to prevent the sprite rotating when the rigidbody rotates. How can I do this?

In other words, I want the simulation to be fine, but I do not want the graphics for this object to rotate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two GameObjects: a parent GameObject containing your `Rigidbody2D` component, and a child GameObject containing your `SpriteRenderer` component.

Then attach a script to the child GameObject that always assigns its `transform.rotation` to be whatever you'd like:

```js
var desiredRotation:Quaternion;

function LateUpdate () {
    transform.rotation = desiredRotation;
}
```

This allows the sprite to maintain its rotation continously, no matter how the rigidbody is rotated.

Answer (score 1):

I've used two GameObjects (parent and child, with the sprite component on the child) and added the following bit of code in the update function of the child:

```
transform.localRotation = transform.localRotation * Quaternion.Inverse(transform.rotation);
```

It did the magic trick :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this script to your `GameObject`

```
void Update () {
    transform.localRotation = new Quaternion ();
}
```